# Ubuntu server 12.04 dependency issues when attempting update

Tags: server, apt, dependencies

I'm having issues updating packages on an Ubuntu Server instance running 12.04.

When running apt-get upgrade:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.37.44) but 3.2.0.38.46 is installed
                Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.37.44) but 3.2.0.38.46 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When using apt-get -f install:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,734 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.37.44); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.38.46.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.37.44); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.38.46.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Yes, I have. The standard approach to unmet dependencies doesn't seem to work here. In this case, linux-server depends on a specific version of linux-image-server and linux-headers-server, no?

Comment: More specifically, I tried apt-get clean, apt-get -f install, and I tried installing the specific versions of linux-image-server and linux-headers-server (got "E: Version '3.2.0.37.44' for 'linux-image-server' was not found", similar for linux-headers-server).

Comment: Oh, didn't see the second link. I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find a solution in the second thread. Had to remove linux-server and mark its dependencies as manually installed.